# What is wrong with google autocomplete?

Tags: google-maps, curl, google-maps-api-3, google-api

**I make a request:** curl -s "[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=штат+нью+йорк&key=](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82+%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E+%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA&key=)< key >"

**Get result:** { "predictions" : [], "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS" }

But when I pass the link in the browser - I get correct result :(

P.S. "штат+нью+йорк" = "state+new+york" ;)

---

**UPDATE**

Problem in word "штат" [ukrainian\russian] ("state" - on english) and **only in curl request**

[image: terminal]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to encode the input string because of the spaces(or for any characters)  used in the input as browser automatically encode those spaces

it should be like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=state%20new%20york&key=
```

as you can see the input is **state new york**

for language related query and results you should also add language parameter in your query

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=штат+нью+йорк&language=ru&key=
```

**After adding language you will get required results**

Comment: In English language it works fine, but on Ukrainian/Russian is not fine.

Comment: @VladVlad then you should add language parameter as well in the url

Comment: Have you tried to URL-encode the complete text 'штат нью йорк'? This will result in `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA&key=api_key`

Comment: @AdeelJaved yep, with language working perfectly, but in browser this parameter is not important, update your answer